# Cannot import modules in node command

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig, swc, swc-compiler

I have this npm command `"create-new": "node --no-warnings --loader ts-node/esm tools/createNewCommand.ts"` in tools directory. If I try to import from src/ I get this error: `CustomError: Cannot find package '@/main.js'`. Maybe the way im running the command is wrong, i dont understand transpiling modules very well, any help or advice is appreciated. thanks

Here are the config files:
tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "typeRoots": ["@types", "./node_modules/@types"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "swc": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "tools/**/*"]
}
```

.swcrc

```
{
  "jsc": {
    "parser": {
      "syntax": "typescript",
      "tsx": false,
      "decorators": true,
      "dynamicImport": true
    },
    "target": "esnext",
    "paths": {
      "@routes/*": ["./src/routes/*"],
      "@middlewares/*": ["./src/middlewares/*"],
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "experimental": {
      "keepImportAssertions": true
    }
  },
  "module": {
    "type": "nodenext"
  }
}
```